# select max from a group by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

I've got a very simple question, I hope.

I have a table MYTABLE like this:

```
FIELD1   FIELD2   FREQ
A1       B        10
A1       C        20
A1       D        5
A2       X        7
A2       Y        12
...
```

and I want to get something like this:

```
enter code here

FIELD1   FIELD2  
A1       C             
A2       Y
```

that is I want to get for every distinct FIELD1 the row having the max(FREQ) but also with its FIELD2 value

Oracle 10g

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Comment: What would be the expected result if also A1 - B had FREQ 20?

Comment: In that case it's fine having the lowest, that would be 'B'

Answer (score 0):

you can use analytical functions to get this done

```
select * from (
select x.*,row_number() over(partition by field1,field2 order by field1 asc) as rnk from (
    select field1
           ,field2
           ,max(field2) over(partition by field1) as max_value
      from mytable
     )x
where max_value=field2
)y
where y.rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions.

```
select FIELD1, FIELD2
from (
   select *, rank() over (partition by FIELD1 order by FREQ desc) rn
   from mytable
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

If you use `RANK()` then you return all rows with `MAX(FREQ)` for each `FIELD1`.

Answer (score 0):

use row_number()

```
select b.* from
(select a.* ,row_number()over (partition by FIELD1 orer by FREQ desc) rn
from table_name a
) b where b.rn=1
```